# How to consume custom objects from Kafka topic in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to consume messages from Kafka's cluster in Spark Streaming using Java API. I am able to consume messages as String but not as an custom object.

My configurations are :

> producer- producerConfig.metadata.broker.list=192.168.56.2:9092
>   producerConfig.zk.connect=192.168.188.104:2181
>   producerConfig.serializer.class=kafka.serializer.StringEncoder
>   producerConfig.request.required.acks=1
>
> consumer- consumerConfig.master=local consumerConfig.cassandraHost=
>   192.168.188.104

```
public class SparkJavaDemo {
    public static void main(String arr[]) {
        String host = "10.206.132.27:2181";// zookeeper
        String group = "test-group";// consumer group name
        Map<String, Integer> consumeJourney = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        consumeJourney.put("test", 5);// topic map --> topic-partition      
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf(true);
        sparkConf.setAppName("Sample");     
        sparkConf.setMaster("local");
        sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "10.206.132.27");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(
                3000));     
        JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> kafkaStream = KafkaUtils
                .createStream(jssc, host, group, consumeJourney);           
        JavaDStream<String> lines = kafkaStream.map(
                new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
                    public String call(Tuple2<String, String> message) {
                        System.out.println("inside map"+message);
                        return message._2();
                    }
                }
            );  
        lines.print();  
        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();
}
```

The above code works.
But, i want to consume message into an object of type Test.
So, I tried modifying javaDStream as :

```
JavaDStream<Test> lines = kafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>,Test>() {             
            @Override
            public Test call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2)
                    throws JSONException,Exception {                
                System.out.println("inside call()");    
                String jsonString = tuple2._2();
                System.out.println(jsonString);
                JSONObject record = (JSONObject) JSON.parse(jsonString);                
                Integer id = record.getInt("id");
                String name = record.getString("name");             
                return new Test(id,name);

            }
});
```

But it does not work.
Please help.

Comment: You need more cores. Try setting the master to "local[*]".

Comment: Did you sort it out? What's the answer? If not, what's the initial error message you've been facing?

Comment: The reason it works to use `local[*]` (or `local[n]` for some large enough `n`) is that Spark Streaming pins each Receiver to a core. You need additional cores for the rest of the processing. So, if you use "local", which is a single core, everything but one thread is starved.

Comment: Thanks @DeanWampler! Seen ["// The master requires 2 cores to prevent from a starvation scenario."](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#a-quick-example) and couldn't believe that was it in this case. Could you post it as an answer?